# How can I drive a boolean field off of a nullable column in a view? (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, view

I created a view in the database. In this case, Score is nullable.

```
SELECT Student.Name, Score.Score
FROM Student JOIN Score ON Student.StudentID = Score.StudentID
```

Now, I would like add a column called "IfScoreIsNull" based on the value of Score to this view. If Score is NOT NULL, the IfScoreIsNull would be 0. Otherwise, it would be 1.

Basically, I'd like the boolean field to be driven by whether or not a Score column is null.

What's the best way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [CASE expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).  These are great for conditionally returning data.  Here is an example:

```
CASE WHEN Score.Score IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IfScoreIsNull
```

This would make your full statement:

```
SELECT 
    Student.Name, 
    Score.Score,
    CASE WHEN Score.Score IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IfScoreIsNull
FROM 
    Student 
        INNER JOIN Score ON Student.StudentID = Score.StudentID
;
```

**EDIT:**  In my original answer I mistakenly called the case expression a case statement.  Statements are the more common form.  Many languages have these, they are used to [control flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow).  In SQL we have case expressions.  These return a scalar value based on an boolean expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in `Sql Server 2012+`. Use [**`IIF`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213574.aspx)

```
select 
     IIF(Score.Score IS NULL,1,0) AS IfScoreIsNUll
     .....
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    Student.Name, 
    Score.Score, 
    CASE WHEN Score.Score IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IfScoreIsNUll
FROM Student JOIN Score ON Student.StudentID = Score.StudentID
```